# I have this while loop : while x == False or y != 10: , but when the Y turn to 10 it keeps to run the loop

Tags: python

I have this code but when the Y turns to 10 it keeps to run the loop, WHY?
I'm a very beginner in python so pls don't think I'm stupid or something :)

```
def destiny_calculator():
    mass = str(input("enter the mass of your material (it could be in gram, milligram, kilogram or ton "))
    if mass.isdigit() == False:
        try:
            float(mass)
        except Exception:
            x = False
            y = 0
            while x == False or y != 10:
                print("Please enter JUST a number")
                mass = str(input("enter the mass of your material (it could be in gram, milligram, kilogram or ton - "))
                y = y + 1
                print (y)
            if y == int(10):
                print("Too many errors")
                exit()
            else:
                pass
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: you would need `and` instead of `or` - `while x == False and y != 10:`

Answer (score 1):

Since you use `or` the code only checks to see if one of the conditions is satisfied. Therefore, as long as `x == False` is true, the code will run. If you want the code to end when `y == 10`, then you should use the `and` operator instead. This will only run the code if both conditions are true and as soon as one becomes false (e.g. `y == 10`) the code will not run.